# Files value in $_FILES gone when browse more files

Tags: javascript, php, file-upload

I'm using krajee bootstrap multiple files input. My image values in `$_FILES` has been gone when I browse more image files.

First browse this `Image1.jpg` and then I browse more image file is `Image2.jpg` by click on browse button again after upload I've got only last image's `Image2.jpg`

I try to `print_r($_FILES["imagenes"]["name"])` after submitted. Here's the result.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Image2.jpg
)
```

How do I keep all files that I've selected when I click to browse more?

My Code:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="input-repl-1a" name="imagenes[]" type="file" class="file-loading" accept="image/*" multiple>
    <button type="submit" name="upload">Upload</button>
</form>
```

Krajee file input

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#input-repl-1a").fileinput({
    uploadUrl: false,
    autoReplace: false,
    overwriteInitial: false,
    showUploadedThumbs: false,
    showUpload: false,
    uploadAsync: false,
    maxFileCount: 5,
    initialPreviewShowDelete: false,
    showRemove: false,
    showClose: false,
    layoutTemplates: {actionDelete: ''}, // disable thumbnail deletion
    allowedFileExtensions: ["jpg", "png", "gif"],
    layoutTemplates: {
        actions: '<div class="file-actions">\n' +
            '    <div class="file-footer-buttons">\n' +
            '        {delete}' +
            '    </div>&nbsp;&nbsp;\n' +
            '</div>',
    }
});
</script>
```

PHP Upload

```
if(isset($_FILES["imagenes"]["name"])) {   
    $TotalImage = count($_FILES['imagenes']['name']);  
    for($i=0;$i<$TotalImage;$i++)
    {
        $filename = $_FILES["imagenes"]["name"][$i];
        $files = $_FILES["imagenes"]["tmp_name"][$i];
        $file_basename = substr($filename, 0, strripos($filename, '.')); // get file extention
        $file_ext = substr($filename, strripos($filename, '.')); // get file name
        $allowed_file_types = array('.jpg','.png', 'jpeg'); 

        if(in_array($file_ext,$allowed_file_types))
        {
            $randOctalName = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);
            $randName = bin2hex($randOctalName).$file_ext;

            $image_to_db = $randName;  

            $width = 640;
            $size = GetimageSize($files);
            $height = round($width*$size[1]/$size[0]);


            if($file_ext == '.jpg') {
                $images_orig = ImageCreateFromJPEG($files);
            } else if($file_ext == '.png') {
                $images_orig = ImageCreateFromPNG($files);
            } else if($file_ext == '.jpeg') {
                $images_orig = ImageCreateFromJPEG($files);
            }

            $photoX = ImagesX($images_orig);
            $photoY = ImagesY($images_orig);
            $images_fin = ImageCreateTrueColor($width, $height);
            ImageCopyResampled($images_fin, $images_orig, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width+1, $height+1, $photoX, $photoY);

            if($file_ext == '.jpg') {
                ImageJPEG($images_fin,"upload/".$randName, 90);
            } else if($file_ext == '.png') {
                ImagePNG($images_fin,"upload/".$randName, 9);
            } else if($file_ext == '.jpeg') {
                ImageJPEG($images_fin,"upload/".$randName, 90);
            }
            ImageDestroy($images_orig);
            ImageDestroy($images_fin);
        } else {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you doing individual AJAX uploads for each file? Then yes, they won't stack up, the file will only be uploaded once and PHP needs to "capture" and store it in that request; the file won't be uploaded again on a subsequent request.

Comment: @deceze I can't do it with Ajax upload 'cause I have more this code `INSERT .. INTO` have to insert product and get the last insert id and go to upload their product images with last insert product id. :(